# most effective way to scale a webpage to different screen sizes

Tags: html, css, layout

At the moment i have a site with many divs set at certain sizes to keep the layout correct.

The only problem is that on some displays the footer is always off the bottom and you have to scroll to it.

I have noticed other sites where no matter the screen resolution, the footer will always auto scale to the bottom of the screen.

Is there a way, other than going through all of my divs and using % for all the heights, to set the footer tag to always be at the bottom of the screen?

My basic site is [jj-triggs.com](http://www.jj-triggs.com) which has a footer that, if on a widescreen monitor or smaller resolutions, pushes the footer off the bottom and you have to scroll to it,

It is possible to fix by changing the size of the divs, but there are so many that would have to be changed. There must be a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: You should change the title to reflect that you want a fixed footer, not adapt your site to different sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you searching for making your footer fixed to the bottom ? If so you can do that with CSS :

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: i could try that, but.... would it create an issue if i have content that opens when you hit a button that will make the page longer? 
my site is jj-triggs.com if you want a reference. cheers

Comment: It wont create any issue, your footer will stick to the page's bottom, that's all. I never used any bootstrap but i think you can always redesign a website using any bootstrap ...

Comment: that worked for making sure it stuck to the bottom of the page, but the only problem is a i have many divs that allow for other content to expand into them, but when they arent open, the divs still create that space which pushes the footer down. Im looking for a way to have the footer at the bottom of the screen until the content is opened and then it can be pushed down.

Answer (score 6):

Without using % it will not fit in all screens correctly.

You can try [bootsrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) I use this to fit in all screens.

Then to fix the footer.

Create a empty div before and make it style to clear:both
or you can try
Position:fixed; bottom:0; 
But this will always keep the footer on screen no matter what the page size is

Comment: yeah that soundsa good idea, just i have content that if clicked, will make the page much longer and then i dont want the footer to still be at the bottom of the screen covering the content if you know what i mean?

Comment: you want to hide the footer if content is clicked or to move footer to another location?

Comment: not really hide...... but make sure it never overlaps any content and is always at the bottom?

Comment: i will give it a try asap and get back to you (: